# multidimensional array tell if a use a value based on flag

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [address] => New York [address_flag] => 0 ) 
[1] => Array ( [address] => London [address_flag] => 1)
```

Lets say i have this array above, `address 1` will always be there while `address 2` can be null how can i get the value of `address 2` if it is available;how can i tell that `address 2` is null or not?

I am getting their value like this

```
foreach (address() as $value) {

echo $value['address']

}
```

`UPDATE`

I want to use the address with flag 0 only if address with flag 1 is not available..how do go about this?any idea is appreciated

Comment: Is your `address()` supposed to be a function?

Comment: Do you just mean `if(isset($value['address']))`?

Comment: if(count($address)>1){echo $address[1];}

Comment: @BrainFooLong it is always set because address with flag 0 is always there my question is how can i tell if address with flag 1 is available and how to get its value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function address(){

$a = array(array ( "address" => "New York", "address_flag" => 0 ), 
           array ( "address" => "London",   "address_flag" => 1 ),
           array ( "address" => "Amsterdam","address_flag" => 1),
           array ( "address" => null,       "address_flag" => null));

return $a;
}

$address = '';
$grouped_by_zero = array();
$grouped_by_one = array();
$array = address();

for ($i=0, $max = count($array); $i < $max; $i++ ){
    foreach($array[$i] as $key => $value) {
      if ($key == "address") {
         $address = $value;
      }     
      if ($key == "address_flag"){
          if ( $value === 0 ){
            array_push($grouped_by_zero,$address);
          } else if ($value === 1) {
              array_push($grouped_by_one,$address);
          }
      }// end outer if      
    }// end foreach
}// end for

foreach($grouped_by_zero as $item){
    echo $item . "\n";
}
echo "\n";
foreach($grouped_by_one as $item){
    echo $item . "\n";
}
//output:

New York

London
Amsterdam
```

Live demo: http://3v4l.org/3utBH

By using the identity operator `===`, a null value is excluded; only a value that is identical to a 0 or 1 is accepted.

Comment: your code is a bit complicated can you just show me if flag is 1 show me address for 1 if flag is 0 address for 0?

Comment: i hope that you can help me again when i need help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php). For example:-

```
foreach (address() as $value) {

   echo isset($value['address']) ? $value['address'] : "";
   echo isset($value['address_flag']) ? $value['address_flag'] : "";

}
```

Comment: can i tell if address_flag is 1 or 0?

Comment: You can check with if condition.